# VSCode not connecting to WSL20.02 when @import Sass partials

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, icons, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

For some reason whenever I begin to type the file path after an `@import` rule in my main.scss file,
VSCode disconnects from WSL2. I am using WSL2 version 20.02 on Windows 10. VSCode is Version 1.54.1 (user setup).

I am pretty new to all this. I am simply trying to import an icon font that I selected from the icomoon.io app and I am using the sass files that the app generated. I am trying to copy and paste the variables into my own sass files. (I will also put the font in my files as well). I have some styles in "main.scss" just to kind of test things and then I have a bunch of variables in the _variables.scss file. I'll type @import and everything is fine but as soon as I begin to type the path within the "" WSL disconnects and cannot even read the _variables.scss or main.scss file, let alone save/write to the files.

I have to close the whole folder and reopen it again from the terminal using `code bjf5201.github.io` (*bjf5201.github.io* being my project folder name)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found out that it was because of the **Color Highlight** extension I was using. After disabling it, everything works fine.
There is an alternative extension **colorize**, which seems to be compatible and does the same thing.